Exchange Shopping soap example
I'm trying to perform an exchange shopping request using Postman following the documentation; however in the sabre page is not that clear for me, there's some sample request:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/search/exchange_shopping
What I've tried is to put the the URL as:

http://services.sabre.com/sp/exchange/shopping/v2_5

this would be the xml body:
<ExchangeShoppingRQ targetCity="AAAA" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/exchange/shopping/v2_5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5.0">
    <STL_Header.RQ>
        <OrchestrationID seq="0">231488734192050161</OrchestrationID>
    </STL_Header.RQ>
    <TicketingProvider>1S</TicketingProvider>
    <PassengerInformation>
        <PassengerWithPNR pnrLocator="TNRUFF" referenceNumber="1.1" firstName="Jhon" lastName="Connor">
            <DocumentNumber>6655333</DocumentNumber>
        </PassengerWithPNR>
    </PassengerInformation>
    <OriginDestinationInformation shopIndicator="true">
        <DateTimeSelection>
            <DepartureDate>2024-12-15</DepartureDate>
        </DateTimeSelection>
        <StartLocation>ATL</StartLocation>
        <EndLocation>LAX</EndLocation>
    </OriginDestinationInformation>
</ExchangeShoppingRQ>

however not working, is there any other detailed guide on how this SOAP request should work?
